# javascript array unsure property array[index] = true/false

Tags: javascript, arrays

I came across this, understood it but still did not know what javascript property it was:

```
var array = [];

array[1] = true;

array[5] = true;

console.log(array) #=> [true, true]

array[0] #=> undefined

array[1]  #=> true

array[2] #=> undefined

array[5] #=> true
```

Can someone explain this for me? Thanks

Comment: `console.log` would have printed `[ , true, , , , true ]`. Please check again.

Comment: Actually it would be `[undefined, true, undefined, undefined, undefined, true]`.

Comment: Or even `[1: true, 5: true]`. Either way, someone should explain.

Comment: Newest chrome prints `[undefined × 1, true, undefined × 3, true]` :-|

Comment: @techfoobar, ugh, that's just nasty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard arrays in JavaScript [aren't really arrays at all](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), and one effect of that is that they're inherently [*sparse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array). That is, an array can have empty slots in it.

That's what you're creating there. After your first three lines, you have an array with two entries in it, at indexes 1 and 5, and a bunch of completely empty slots (indexes 0, 2, 3, 4). Its `length` property would be `6`. When you try to retrieve an element that doesn't exist from an array, you get the value `undefined`. (This is just a specific case of JavaScript's general behavior: If you try to retrieve an object property that doesn't exist, you get the value `undefined`.)

The output of `console.log` with a sparse array will vary depending on what the implementation of `console.log` does with them. The comments on the question suggest that there are various different ways the console may show the array. You might look at using `console.log(array.join())` to get more consistent results. That would give you `,true,,,,true`, because it shows blanks for array entries that don't exist (or that contain the value `undefined`, but in your case, they don't exist).

Comment: Arrays are arrays, but not in Javascript. They may be called Array, but they're really hash objects. The index is just a property, and it has some extra methods that help it pretend to be an array.